# Airflow: Cannot start local instance

Tags: python, airflow

I tried to start the local instance by:

```
$ docker build -t zipongo/airflow:latest .
$ docker-compose -f docker/compose/LocalExecutor.yml up -d
```

When I tried to open the local instance (.0.0.0:8080/admin/) I get an error saying that page does not exist.

Upon further digging, I typed in and get:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                         PORTS                    NAMES
eab50acd612c        zipongo/airflow:latest   "/entrypoint.sh webs…"   30 minutes ago      Restarting (1) 4 seconds ago                            compose_webserver_1
11a9723cec26        postgres:9.6             "docker-entrypoint.s…"   30 minutes ago      Up 30 minutes                  0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   compose_postgres_1
```

I tried to use:

```
$ $ docker exec -it eab50acd612c bash
Error response from daemon: Container eab50acd612ce942b5249d9daaa5456c215ed454870dc57c7800d74d9391535c is restarting, wait until the container is running
```

I also did:

```
$ docker logs --tail 50 --follow --timestamps eab50acd612c
2018-02-10T18:19:06.738878841Z airflow.exceptions.AirflowConfigException: The value for configuration option "webserver:authenticate" is not a boolean (received "").
2018-02-10T18:20:07.403788323Z Initialize database...
2018-02-10T18:20:07.437835491Z psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
2018-02-10T18:20:07.437884667Z  Is the server running locally and accepting
2018-02-10T18:20:07.437894762Z  connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
2018-02-10T18:20:07.474564318Z psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
2018-02-10T18:20:07.474614592Z  Is the server running locally and accepting
2018-02-10T18:20:07.474624787Z  connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
2018-02-10T18:20:07.540415576Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-02-10T18:20:07.540451757Z   File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 17, in <module>
2018-02-10T18:20:07.540462352Z     from airflow import configuration
2018-02-10T18:20:07.540471148Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
2018-02-10T18:20:07.540481543Z     from airflow import configuration as conf
2018-02-10T18:20:07.540490138Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 784, in <module>
2018-02-10T18:20:07.540499034Z     conf.read(AIRFLOW_CONFIG)
2018-02-10T18:20:07.540520623Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 636, in read
2018-02-10T18:20:07.540528019Z     self._validate()
2018-02-10T18:20:07.540536615Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 551, in _validate
2018-02-10T18:20:07.540544311Z     self.getboolean("webserver", "authenticate") and
2018-02-10T18:20:07.540550908Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 626, in getboolean
2018-02-10T18:20:07.540559504Z     'boolean (received "{}").'.format(section, key, val))
2018-02-10T18:20:07.540568699Z airflow.exceptions.AirflowConfigException: The value for configuration option "webserver:authenticate" is not a boolean (received "").
2018-02-10T18:20:07.611814558Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-02-10T18:20:07.611848841Z   File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 17, in <module>
2018-02-10T18:20:07.611858936Z     from airflow import configuration
2018-02-10T18:20:07.611867232Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
2018-02-10T18:20:07.611875728Z     from airflow import configuration as conf
2018-02-10T18:20:07.611884023Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 784, in <module>
2018-02-10T18:20:07.611892419Z     conf.read(AIRFLOW_CONFIG)
2018-02-10T18:20:07.611900515Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 636, in read
2018-02-10T18:20:07.611909011Z     self._validate()
2018-02-10T18:20:07.611917207Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 551, in _validate
2018-02-10T18:20:07.611925703Z     self.getboolean("webserver", "authenticate") and
2018-02-10T18:20:07.611933998Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 626, in getboolean
2018-02-10T18:20:07.611942294Z     'boolean (received "{}").'.format(section, key, val))
2018-02-10T18:20:07.611950590Z airflow.exceptions.AirflowConfigException: The value for configuration option "webserver:authenticate" is not a boolean (received "").
2018-02-10T18:20:07.613190770Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-02-10T18:20:07.613215357Z   File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 17, in <module>
2018-02-10T18:20:07.613226152Z     from airflow import configuration
2018-02-10T18:20:07.613237147Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
2018-02-10T18:20:07.613246342Z     from airflow import configuration as conf
2018-02-10T18:20:07.613253338Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 784, in <module>
2018-02-10T18:20:07.613262534Z     conf.read(AIRFLOW_CONFIG)
2018-02-10T18:20:07.613271329Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 636, in read
2018-02-10T18:20:07.613290620Z     self._validate()
2018-02-10T18:20:07.613300115Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 551, in _validate
2018-02-10T18:20:07.613309011Z     self.getboolean("webserver", "authenticate") and
2018-02-10T18:20:07.613317906Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 626, in getboolean
2018-02-10T18:20:07.613326802Z     'boolean (received "{}").'.format(section, key, val))
2018-02-10T18:20:07.613335597Z airflow.exceptions.AirflowConfigException: The value for configuration option "webserver:authenticate" is not a boolean (received "").
```

I am not sure where it's wrong.

Comment: Have you started the postgres server since the error said: `psql: could not connect to server`

Comment: It seems to be running.

docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                       PORTS                    NAMES
eab50acd612c        zipongo/airflow:latest   "/entrypoint.sh webs…"   3 hours ago         Restarting (1) 2 hours ago                            compose_webserver_1
11a9723cec26        postgres:9.6             "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 hours ago         Up 3 hours                   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   compose_postgres_1

Comment: Another useful way to see logs just relating to the `webserver` container: `docker-compose -f docker-compose-LocalExecutor.yml logs webserver`. What does that return?

Comment: Oh wow, didn't know that. Here it is:

ERROR: .IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'./docker-compose-LocalExecutor.yml'